# Error in Python Binary Search Algorithm when using pseudocode

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, indexing

So I'm trying to make a recursive binary search algorithm and here is the pseudocode I'm using:

```
BINARY-SEARCH(X, A, start, end)
1  if start > end then
2     return False
3  middle = ((end - start) / 2) + start
4  if X = A[middle] then
5     return True
6  else if X < A[middle] then
7     return BINARY-SEARCH(X, A, start, middle - 1)
8  else
9     return BINARY-SEARCH(X, A, middle + 1, end)
```

and here's my program:

```
def binarySearchRec(value, list, start, end):
    if start > end:
        return False
    middle = ((end - start) / 2) + start
    if value == list[middle]:
        return True
    elif value < list[middle]:
        return binarySearchRec(value, list, start, middle - 1)
    else:
        return binarySearchRec(value, list, middle + 1, end)
```

and so I keep getting an index error whenever I use a value that is not in the list, but it works fine for finding values that are in the list, any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: hint: python lists are zero-indexed

Comment: Can you give us examples for value, list, start, and end that product the exception? Also, you might want to use a variable name other than list because you are stomping on the built-in type. I normally use data as the name when I am using a list type.

Comment: The pseudo-code uses an inclusive upper bound, which means that `end` is a valid index. You have to pass `len(a) - 1` as `end` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 'start' and 'end' properly? I just ran your function and it works well for values not in the list (False is returned).

Answer (score 0):

Since the answer has been given away already I suggest you try to approach the problem from another angle - by testing it:

> whenever I use a value that is not in the list, but it works fine for finding values that are in the list

Interestingly the code does not fail on *every* number not in the array. Try with `array = range(1,10,2)` and search e.g. 2, 4, 6, 8 -- all not in the array. It will work. Search 10 and it will fail. That's a hint that something is probably wrong with limit checking, rather than the implementation as such.

> any help would be greatly appreciated

Here is a way to test your function and quickly see on what numbers it is failing:

```
from itertools import izip_longest as izipl
def complement(a):
    return list(set(range(min(a), max(a) + 10)) - set(a))
array = range(1,10,2)
c_array = complement(array)
start = 0
end = len(array) # that's the culprit
try:
    for a,b in izipl(array, c_array):
        if a:
            assert binarySearchRec(a, array, start, end), "expected to find %s" % a
        if b:
            assert not binarySearchRec(b, array, start, end), "did not expect to find %s" % b
        print  "worked on", a, b
except:
    print "failed on", a, b
else:
    print "all is well"
=> 
worked on 1 2
worked on 3 4
worked on 5 6
worked on 7 8
failed on 9 10
```